# Using graph6 format with graph-tool

Tags: graph, graph-tool

I have downloaded a bunch of graphs from [http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/graphs.html](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/data/graphs.html) and I want to do some analysis. I want to use the `graph-tool` Python module for this but I cant find a convenient way to convert from `graph6` format to a format compatible with `graph-tools`. There must be an easy way to do this... any help would be appreciated.

-- EDIT:
A possible solution is convert from g6 to gt format... but I haven't found any tools that do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `graph6` format looks annoying to work with, but fortunately the [documentation](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/data/formats.html) mentions a tool named `showg` for pretty-printing graphs.  It's easy to simply parse the output of that program.

First, build the `showg` tool.  (Use `clang` or `gcc` as appropriate for your system. Or just download the binary they provide on their website.)

```sh
$ curl -s http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/data/showg.c > showg.c
$ clang -o showg showg.c
$ ./showg --help
```

Download some example data and look at it. I think the `-e` option produces the easiest output to work with.

```sh
$ curl -s http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/data/graph4.g6 > graph4.g6

$ ./showg -p10 -e graph4.g6

Graph 10, order 4.
4 5
0 2  0 3  1 2  1 3  2 3
```

Here's a simple script that reads the edge list from `./showg -p<N> -e` and creates a `graph_tool.Graph` object:

```py
# load_graph.py
import sys
import graph_tool as gt

# Read stdin and parse last line as a list of edge pairs
line = sys.stdin.readlines()[-1]
nodes = [int(n) for n in line.split()]
n0 = nodes[0::2]
n1 = nodes[1::2]
edges = list(zip(n0, n1))

# Load graph
g = gt.Graph()
g.add_edge_list(edges)

print("Loaded graph with the following edges:")
print(g.get_edges())
```

Let's give it a try:

```sh
$ ./showg -p10 -e graph4.g6 | python load_graph.py
Loaded graph with the following edges:
[[0 2]
 [0 3]
 [1 2]
 [1 3]
 [2 3]]
```

Comment: thanks! I was working along similar lines but hoped there was some nice alternative. It is a shame that graph-tool doesn't provide an efficient loader for graph6, maybe the format isn't widely used enough...

Comment: Here the code is converting a single graph. What if we generate many graphs in bulk using `geng`?

Comment: When I run `geng 8 | showg -p12346 -e -q`, it produces three lines of output. So the above code only captures the last line: `[(2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7), (4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 7), (5, 6), (5, 7), (6, 7)]` It should be `[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7), (4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 7), (5, 6), (5, 7), (6, 7)]`